# Random uneditable node

Tags: drupal, permissions, edit

I have come across this problem in the past but never solved it.

I am on the verge of finishing a Drupal site for a client. I created two content types and gave him the permissions necessary to edit any occurrence of these node types.

**The strange problem is the client can edit any node of type product_type except for one particular node of the same type**.
So in other words, all nodes of type **product_type** are editable except node/3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the issue was. The client account could not edit anything with full-html input format.
I enabled that at /admin/settings/filters and it works just fine now.

Thanks for looking in.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a node access module installed, like Content Access or Taxonomy Access Control? If you do, it could be that there are per-node permissions set and your client's role doesn't have permission to edit that node, or it could be that it is tagged with a particular taxonomy term which prevents him from editing it.

If you don't have any extra node access modules installed, is it just that the link to "Edit" is missing in the tabs section of the page? Can the client type in "http://example.com/node/3/edit" and reach the edit screen that way?

If you supply an answer to these questions in the comments, I'll edit this answer as best I can.

Comment: Thanks semperos. I have no other modules installed which might affect individual nodes editability. Nor am I even using any taxonomies. As for doing something like http://example.com/node/3/edit, I tried that and was given an access denied message. Meanwhile, node/4, which is the same type as node/3, is fine and perfectly editable.

Answer (score 0):

Check the author of the node. If it's different than the client's user account that may account for the problem. If that does not work you may need to "rebuild permissions."